# Returning API JSON through a proxy in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I'm trying console log the json for an API after sending my request through a proxy, however when the code runs the console logs nothing. Here is my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
    let steamIdValue = request.body.steamId
    let steamInventoryApiLink = 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' + steamIdValue + '/inventory/json/730/2'

    require('request-promise')({
        url: 'xxxxx',
        proxy: 'xxxxx'
    }).then(function(data){

        const request = require('request');

        request({
          'url': steamInventoryApiLink,
          'method': "GET",
          'proxy':'http://' + data + ':80'
        },function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
          }
        })
        
        
        }, function(err){ console.error(err); });

});
```

Is there a fix, or a better way to go about doing this?

***BELOW IS A LOG WITH THE SUGGESTED CHANGES***

(using 'request-promise' in both requests and logging the error, and the ip address.)

```
Aleeshas-MacBook-Pro:LoopTradesRound2 aleeshamoseley$ node index.js
listening at 3000
193.8.1.88
RequestError: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 193.8.1.88:80
    at new RequestError (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Request.onRequestError (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ClientRequest.onError (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:179:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    ... 5 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  cause: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 193.8.1.88:80
      at ClientRequest.onError (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:177:17)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  },
  error: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 193.8.1.88:80
      at ClientRequest.onError (/Users/aleeshamoseley/Desktop/LoopTradesRound2/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:177:17)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
  },
  options: {
    url: 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198034202275/inventory/json/730/2',
    method: 'GET',
    proxy: 'http://193.8.1.88:80',
    callback: [Function: RP$callback],
    transform: undefined,
    simple: true,
    resolveWithFullResponse: false,
    transform2xxOnly: false
  },
  response: undefined
}
```

Comment: Which `console.log` statement do you expect to do anything? Also, running this code will do nothing but to open a http server on  port 3000 (which should log *listening at 3000*), are you actually sending a request to the `/api` route? Please show us how you are sending that request, and notice that your server never responds to that request.

Comment: You're making 3 (and counting the external proxies, 5) requests here, which is way too many! Which of them does not work?

Comment: Why are you mixing `request` and `request-promise` in the same code?

Comment: I am actually sending a request to the /api route, and it definitely works as whatever is sent gets logged to the console. I may just be confused and trying the wrong method to send my API request through a proxy, if thats the case do you know another way I could go about doing it?

Comment: It seems to be the final request that isn't working.

Comment: My goal is to request the api from my server through the proxy, and then have the response as a json.

Comment: "*whatever is sent gets logged to the console*" and "*when the code runs the console logs nothing*" don't align. Please edit your question to clarify, maybe post the logs you get.

Comment: "*send my API request through a proxy*" - which proxy, the `http://pfjbcgbo-rotate:lqu606fkc326@p.webshare.io:80` one or the one whose hostname you get back from `http://ipv4.webshare.io/`? And by "*my API request*" you mean the request to `steamInventoryApiLink`, not the `/api` request to your own server?

Comment: The one who's host name I get back is the proxy I am trying to send it through. And yes i do mean the `steamInventoryApiLink`. What I meant is that the steamIdValue is sent to the server through the /api request perfectly fine and can be console.logged, however when I try to get the json from the `steamInventoryApiLink` via a proxy nothing is console.logged, and when I remove the error catch and try to log the `body` the console logs `undefined`.

Comment: Please add a `console.log(data)` (so we know you got back a good proxy hostname), and add a  `console.log(error, body)` to the inner callback, then post the logs you're getting.

Comment: Also, as recommended before, better use the `request-promise` package also for the second request, instead of the weird mix between promise and callback style. Write `require('request-promise')({'url': steamInventoryApiLink, 'method': "GET", 'proxy':'http://' + data + ':80'}).then(console.log, console.error);`

Comment: I've made all the changes you've suggested and posted a log. Thanks a lot for the help so far.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the problem is that `http://193.8.1.88:80` is not a valid proxy address. Check with webshare.io why they returned an IP address from their API that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement. If the statuscode is not 200, but is somehow still accepted as 'not an error', the error catch does not work, so add an else to that if and in it log an error message, or just delete the if statement to get the response no matter what it may be.

Comment: I've removed it and I'm trying to `console.log(body)` now but just receive undefined in the console.

Comment: @LostInTheCSSauce Then consider logging the `error` instead

Comment: I now receive: `Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED`